# How do I show progress bar before showing activity

Tags: android

Below is my java code and xml code.  I want to show progress bar before showing any data. How can I do that?  I'm using asyntask for loading data.  How will I show progressbar in my code to first show progressbar until data is loaded.  When data is loaded, the progress bar is removed.

```
public class fifthscreen extends Activity {
    String num = null;
    TextView ingredient;

long Menu_ID;
String dish_name;
View row4;

View row3;

String status;

HorizontalListView listview;
CategoryListAdapter3 cla;
String DescriptionAPI;

TextView txt1, txt2, txt3;
ImageView img1;
String URL, URL2;
String SelectMenuAPI;
static ArrayList<Long> Category_ID = new ArrayList<Long>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_name = new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> Category_image = new ArrayList<String>();
public static String allergen2;
private AQuery androidAQuery;
String name;

String description;
String url1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fifthscreen);

    ingredient = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ingredient);
    img1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_button_image);

    txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.menuname);
    txt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

    Intent iGet = getIntent();

    ImageView options = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.options5);
    androidAQuery = new AQuery(this);


    options.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(fifthscreen.this,
                    LinkButtons.class);
            startActivity(iMenuList);
        }
    });

    dish_name = iGet.getStringExtra("dish_name");

    listview = (HorizontalListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listview2);

    cla = new CategoryListAdapter3(fifthscreen.this);

    new getDataTask().execute();
    ImageView btnback = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnback);

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

void clearData() {
    Category_ID.clear();
    Category_name.clear();
    Category_image.clear();
}

public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    getDataTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txt1.setText(name);
        txt3.setText(description);
        androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, false, false);
        listview.setAdapter(cla);
    }
}

public void parseJSONData() {

    SelectMenuAPI = Utils.dishdescription + dish_name;

    clearData();
    URL = SelectMenuAPI;
    URL2 = URL.replace(" ", "%20");

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpConnectionParams
                .setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
        HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(URL2);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                atomInputStream),8192);

        String line;
        String str = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            str += line;
        }

        JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject(str);

        status = json2.getString("status");
        if (status.equals("1")) {

            JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");

            for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {

                name = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("name");

                description = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString(
                        "description");

                url1 = school2.getJSONObject(0).getString("image");
            }

            JSONObject school3 = json2.getJSONObject("dish_nutrition");

final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table2);

            for (int j = 0; j < school3.length(); j++) {

                String s = String.valueOf(j + 1);

    row3 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.rows, null);
    ((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.localTime))

   .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("qty"));
((TextView) row3.findViewById(R.id.apprentTemp))

  .setText(school3.getJSONObject(s).getString("name"));


                fifthscreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        table.addView(row3);
                    }
                });
            }

            JSONArray school4 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_allergen");
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < school4.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = school4.getJSONObject(i);

                Category_ID.add((long) i);
                Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
                Category_image.add(object.getString("image"));
            }

            final LinearLayout table3 = (LinearLayout)  
    findViewById(R.id.table3);

            JSONArray school5 = json2.getJSONArray("dish_ingredient");

            for (int i = 0; i < school5.length(); i++) {

row4 = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row2, null);
((TextView)  row4.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(school5

      .getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
                ((TextView) row4.findViewById(R.id.subingredients))
                        .setText(school5.getJSONObject(i).getString(
                                "sub_ingredients"));

                // table3.addView(row2);

                fifthscreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        table3.addView(row4);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        else {

            JSONArray school2 = json2.getJSONArray("data");
            for (int i = 0; i < school2.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject object = school2.getJSONObject(i);

                Category_ID.add((long) i);
                Category_name.add(object.getString("name"));
            }
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    //   IOConnect = 1;
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
   }



  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#E5E5E5"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layoutbordercolor" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnback"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="3dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bitmap"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:src="@drawable/logostar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="12dp"
                android:text="San Diego Unified"
                android:textColor="#603311"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:text="SCHOOL DISTRICT"
                android:textColor="#603311"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/options1" />
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/editbackground"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/search_btn" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
           android:paddingLeft="10dp"
           android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
           android:paddingRight="5dp"
           android:gravity="left"
            android:background="#FFF"
            android:hint="  Search School by name"
              android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
          android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp" >
        </EditText>
    </RelativeLayout>


      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pleaseselect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:text=" Select a school type"
        android:textColor="#0A2A1B"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytContent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_border"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMainMenuhome"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:paddingTop="3dp"
   android:paddingBottom="3dp"
   android:paddingLeft="3dp"
   android:paddingRight="3dp"
            android:dividerHeight="1dip"
            android:fadeScrollbars="true"
          android:listSelector="@color/listview_selector"

            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!--   android:listSelector="@drawable/listviewborder" -->


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

          />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/alert"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you just paste your entire project? :P

Answer (score 1):

You can make a relative layout covering the whole screen with it's background and the progress bar in the middle, on top of all you're activity content, once you have all the information you need, you can just dismiss that layout overlaying the whole activity layout and that would do the trick. This is not a clean approach but is commonly used.

In order to do something better, you could create a completely separate layout and just having the progress as part of the activity until you gather all the information needed for your content Data, just inflate it and show it, your progress bar should be reusable so you can show and dismiss the progress whenever you need it...

Hope this Helps.

Regards!

Comment: give any example what u say

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Let me know if it works.

```
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(fifthscreen.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Your Title");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parseJSONData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txt1.setText(name);
        txt3.setText(description);
        androidAQuery.id(img1).image(url1, false, false);
        listview.setAdapter(cla);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: but i dont want to show any layout before load data like ic_launcher on imageview

Comment: Are you referring to an Android Splash Screen?

Comment: no no is my fifth step screen after fourh step so i want when i click first show only progressbar when finish then show acticvity

Comment: it ispossible hide main linearlayout and show on postexecute? and untill then show progressbar??